# Get user email using FQL

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the following FQL to get birthdays from Facebook ( I am aware that teh api has changed) However I want to continue with this for now:

```
String fqlQuery = "{" +
                        "'friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()'," +
                        "'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name,pic_square, birthday FROM user WHERE uid IN" +
                        "(SELECT uid2 FROM #friends) AND birthday'"+
                        "}";
```

How to modify this query so that I can fetch users email id ( not friends)

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Authorize the user with the "email" permission and call `/me` with the Graph API to get the email of the user. This is a LOT easier with the Graph API, forget about FQL. A code example for Android can be found in the "Reading" section of the reference page i posted.

Btw, if you want to get the emails of friends: that´s not possible at all, not even with the old API. You would not be allowed to use those emails in any way, so it would be pointless to get emails of friends.

Comment: I am impressing on diong this with the above is because the fql in my question is triggered as soon as login button is hit, I thought addition to the same fql would solve my purpose in the easiest possible manner. With teh approach you suggest I will have to change my program structure. I have already established the permissions for self email and everything is setup.

Comment: you can´t do that in one fql call anyway. and using the graph api is a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how many thousand "Friend's birthday reminder" apps are out there... @luschn is right. I don't understand what you want to query. `friends_*` permissions have been revoked with the introduction of Graph API v2.0.

FQL will be available until August 7th 2016, but only if you have a <=v2.0 app.

The FQL would be

```
String fqlQuery = "{" +
    "'email':'SELECT uid, email FROM user WHERE uid = me()'," +
    "'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name,pic_square, birthday FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND birthday'"+
"}";
```

This effectively can only work with v1.0 apps, which will stop working on April 30th 2015.

Comment: I am aware of the issue, but I would effectively roll out an update somewhere in mid march. Because I am making my app server based now and users can take backup of thier data before open graph becomes closed graph. For this I need an email id to separate users and their data on my servers. Thats why an email ID.

Comment: email returns me null somehow. When I try to retrieve it like: `email = jsonObject.getString("email")`

Comment: So, have you gathered the *email* permission upon login? Otherwise you can't access the email field.

Comment: Yes I have, I had to make a separate query by dividing your solution into two queries, that did work!